# Remote Debugging Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I've been refactoring some code which was previously working.

Now when debugging I get to a break point in the refactored code and when I step into the Property in question I get a message saying that Windows firewall is currently blocking remote debugging.

It doesn't make sense because the application is a console application being debugged through visual studio on my local machine. I am using VS2010 and .net 4.0.

Does anyone know why vs might be trying to remote debug?

Comment: The remote debugger is also used when your program runs in 64-bit mode.  VS is a 32-bit app so the remote debugger is required to bridge the gap.  Anti-malware is usually a troublemaker next.  You can force 32-bit mode for your app with Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.

Answer (score 0):

what does your code do? does it access any external files and or databases? 
It could also be an administratrion issue, try rightclicking VS and run as admin first off and see if that fixes the issue. 
secondly trace your code and see if there is any links to externals, and thirdly go to windows firewall and change the settings to allow access to Visual studios~ and or databases/.net instances.